# KafkaStreams persistent state store returns only fraction of all keys

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using KafkaStreams pre-2.5 version.
So I'm getting the read-only store this way:

```
ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, Object> store = streams.store("store_name", QueryableStoreTypes.<String, Object>keyValueStore());
Iterator<KeyValue<String, Object>> itr = store.all();
long keyCounter = 0;
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    itr.next();
    counter++;
}
```

In  this case the counter has the expected value.

But if I do the same on the persistent store in Punctuator, I only see the fraction of expected values, although I use the same state store name.
I assume that because the state store name is the same, I would be getting same values, but this is not true.

```
@Override
public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
    KeyValueStore<String, Object> stateStore = 
        (KeyValueStore<String, Object>) context.getStateStore(this.stateStoreName);
    context.schedule(Duration.ofDays(1),
        PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, getPunctuator(stateStore));
}

private static Punctuator getPunctuator(KeyValueStore<String, Object> stateStore) {
    return timestamp -> {
          long counter = 0;
          try (final KeyValueIterator<String, Object> iter = stateStore.all()) {
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                iter.next();
                counter++
            }
          }
        });
    };
}
```

What am I doing wrong? why the persistent state store is not getting the full set of the keys while the read-only store does?

========================EDIT=========================

I suspect this is because I have a persistent store per partition and a separate stream thread per partition. So every stream thread gets the persistent store only having keys from the partition to which the stream thread is assigned. So combined together, if I multiply the counter by X partitions I have, I roughly get the expected number, which would explain what's going on.
Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 3):

> this is because I have a persistent store per partition and a separate stream thread per partition

Correct. You need to [Query state from the entire app](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html#querying-remote-state-stores-for-the-entire-app).